# How to logout user when $_SESSION variable expires

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I'm trying to implement a MySQL table that contains a list of users that are currently logged in. This is my current logic and code to implement this.

On Log In execute the following code:

```
//Add the user_id to the logged_in table
$loggedInQry = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO logged_in (user_id) VALUES ('$userId')");
```

Upon clicking the Logout button, execute the following code:

```
//Remove user from logged_in table.
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$logoutQry = mysqli_query($dbc, "DELETE FROM logged_in WHERE user_id = '$userId'");

//Clear all of the saved session variables.
session_destroy();
```

The problem i'm currently facing however, is that if the session times out after the default 24 minutes, the user is automatically logged out due to the unsetting of the `$_SESSION['userId']` variable, however the user_id is not removed from the logged_in table.

Is there a way that a function can be executed on a `$_SESSION` timeout? Ideally i would like to remove the current `$_SESSION['userId']` from the logged_in table upon a Session timeout, as it currently remains in the logged_in table.

Comment: why not give a session a life time and only terminate it when the user have requested to?

Comment: And is also its important to validate the logout request is a valid request from your users..

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own session timeout mechanism so you can execute that same delete query upon timeout.

This will get you going in the right direction: https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/08/implementing-session-timeout-with-php/

Comment: Your answer could be more useful if you can take the important parts of that link and post them as part of your answer then reference the link, currently if that link changes/get deleted  your answer loses value

Answer (score 0):

Auto expire session

```
<?php
session_start();
$idletime=30;//after 60 seconds the user gets logged out
if (time()-$_SESSION['timestamp']>$idletime){
session_destroy();
}else{
$_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
}

$_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
```

Comment: 60 seconds is one minute